# sql server convert string representing datetime to date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to cast a string '2019-31-01 09:00:00' to a date.

```
SELECT CAST('2019-31-01 09:00:00.000' AS date);
```

SQL Server returns an error message: failed conversion of the date and/or time from a character string.

Whereas

```
DECLARE @MyDate AS datetime = '2019-31-01 00:00:00';
SELECT CAST(@MyDate AS date)    
--2019-01-31
```

Works. Because of the Locale. Confusing ?

Comment: The month and day are probably mixed in the string literal.

Comment: What are the expected results? i assume `2019-31-01` without the time  ?

Comment: Yes. I just input YY:DD:MM instead of YY:MM:DD. That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a reasonable date/time format (YYYY-MM-DD):

```
SELECT CAST('2019-01-31 09:00:00.000' AS date);
```

Or what Microsoft recommends:

```
SELECT CAST('2019-01-31T09:00:00.000' AS date);
```

Note:  You will lose the time component.

Comment: @RaymondNijland no it won't, the `date` data type has no time component.

Comment: Yes, because dB fiddle had its own display formats. Try a `datetime2(7)` on that site. You get the same format.

Comment: *"Yes, because dB fiddle had its own display formats. Try a datetime2(7) on that site. You get the same format"* @Larnu that is pretty annoying as i don't have a (local) SQL Server to test on but right good to know.. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/340e0/117  removing the comments..

Comment: @RaymondNijland . . . SQLFiddle does a more accurate job representing dates.

Comment: *"SQLFiddle does a more accurate job representing dates"* yes i noticed..

Answer (score 1):

Date format to be in : `yyyy-mm-dd`:

```
SELECT CAST('2019-01-31 09:00:00.000' AS date);
```